# Can I pause Unity Setup download and continue it whenever possible as per convenience(using Unity Hub)?

Tags: unity

Actually I get only 1.5GB data daily. So it's not possible for me to download the whole Unity setup in a day. So I wanted to know if I can pause and resume download process as per convenience. I am downloading using Unity Hub.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. I'm not sure this is on-topic for the site as it's more technical support than game dev. From what I could see, pause/resume isn't available using Unity Hub. There are a couple of work arounds proposed in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-we-have-a-pause-download-resume-download-button-in-unity-hub-and-more-info-when-downloading.864046/).

Comment: @Pikalek Thanks a lot. I've got my answer in the discussion link you've provided.